# MESSAGING app keeps on crashing on 520

Tags: windows-10-mobile, messaging, system-apps, crash

My 520 is running on 10586.494. it was working okay till today morning. Out of nowhere, the messaging app either keeps crashing when i try to open it or shows 
**loading.....** .

Soft reset didn't solve the problem. What is the root cause to this problem? I haven't experienced anything like this before. To make matters worse, am not even getting notifications.

Please help me ASAP. Any way to solve this other than doing a hard reset?

.